# Why would you ever make a unique pointer to a primitive type in c++?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I just found this code and who knows where or when it came from, but it's the end of a function and rather than returning a simple int64_t type, it makes a unique_ptr to it.

I'm just wondering if anybody can explain where this usage has value?

```
return std::make_unique<int64_t>(off);
```

Update:

It isn't being used this way, but as I commented below, one possible use of a pointer to primitive vs just the primitive is that you can set the pointer to null and thus add a flag to the integer as in error or not available.

Comment: I might found usage for `std::shared_ptr<int>` but not for `std::unique_ptr<int>`.

Comment: It might make sense in the context where it was created. There is a lot of code that makes little sense out of context.

Comment: Programming in general never ceases to surprise me with edge-cases that make conventional wisdom and rules of thumb fail hilariously, so odds are decent that out there in the deep-dark of some really bizarre case there is a use for this. I don't see one, though. Can you give more context on how this is being used?

Comment: It's just returning the number, although I thought of a use case. an int64_t can represent all the integer values possible in 64 bits. a pointer to an int64_t can represent all the same integer values as well as null, so you can use it as a flag or something, it gives you an additional value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a variable of primitive type as

```
int64_t foo;
```

Means `foo` is placed on the stack and is [block-scoped](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope#Block_scope) (i.e., it goes out of scope at the end of the block). More formally using C++ terms it has [automatic storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

> The object is allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block and deallocated at the end. All local objects have this storage duration, except those declared static, extern or thread_local.

On the other hand, using a `unique_ptr`...

```
auto foo = std::make_unique<int64_t>(off);
```

... allocates memory for the `int64_t` on the heap. Formally, it has [dynamic storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

> The object is allocated and deallocated per request by using dynamic memory allocation functions.

You can do this yourself by declaring a pointer to an `int64_t` and using `new`:

```
int64_t *foo = new int64_t;
```

But then you have to make sure you don't forget to `delete` that pointer. That's where `unique_ptr` comes in. It deletes the pointer it owns when it goes out of scope. This is [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). You can also transfer ownership to a different `unique_ptr` instance.

Comment: The programmer has the exact same control over the plain old `int64_t` Both go out of scope when the programmer lets them go out of scope.

Comment: @user4581301 there are really two questions; why dynamically allocate a primitive (or indeed anything), and why use `unique_ptr`. `unique_ptr` is a smart wrapper around a pointer and the reasons for using it are obvious and well covered elsewhere. Reasons for dynamically allocating storage for a primitive type are that you want it to stay in the same spot in memory beyond the current block. Maybe you need to pass a pointer to it to someone who requires that the pointer remain valid later. You can't do that with an automatic-storage variable.

Comment: We read the question differently. I see it as "Why would someone got to all the trouble of making a `unique_ptr` to a data type so small and simple that there is no obvious advantage?"

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful for a function to attach to a memory-mapped address and return a pointer to it through a unique_ptr, with a custom deleter that cleans up when user is done with it.

Comment: 458 had what I was thinking: why bother going through all the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of a `unique_ptr` pointed-to integer can be extended by moving the `unique_ptr` to some other spot.

The lifetime of an automatic storage integer ends when it scope or enclosing object does.

In the event that not just the value, but the identity, of the integer matters, then `unique_ptr` can solve problems a raw integer cannot.

For example, I can pair that `unique_ptr` with a thread.  The thread can be responsible for writing information to said `unique_ptr`.

The thread is movable; a raw integer is not.  So the semantics of the two disagree, so you cannot shove a thread and a primitive int into a struct or class and use default move operations.

If you use a thread and a unique ptr to a primitive type, you can toss it into a struct and use default move operations and they work.

You could use a shared ptr, but if we presume the two objects (unique ptr and thread) are bound in a structure where the thread is destroyed first, no other sharing is requried, and shared ptr has overhead costs.  In addition, a shared ptr if exposed leads to ownership tracking hell.  The runtime cost of a shared ptr is a mixture of the second allocation and the atomic increment/decrement leading to concurrency contention costs.  The compiletime cost is that the ownership semantics get more complex than a unique ptr.

It is more likely to be a bad design decision, but there are possible reasons why it wouldn't be.

Comment: Anywhere that you can transfer the value of the unique_ptr you can just as easily pass the primitive value as well (and the primitive will be quicker and less resource consuming)

Comment: Everybody always mentions the overhead of shared_ptr vs unique_ptr, but it seems to me the tradeoff is that you have to litter your program with std::move() all over the place just to make unique_ptr work that way, where as if you use shared_ptr you can just mostly treat your variable like a pointer and it all just works. The few cycles it saves will be made up by intel's latest chip next year. If you're not a HFT, I think you shouldn't really be worrying about the overhead of a shared_ptr vs unique_ptr compared to the mess you have to make in your program to make unique_ptr work correctly.

Comment: @stu First, shared ptr increases contention due to atomic operations; more cores, shared ptr costs more.  So no, it gets worse not better over time.  Second, ownership semantics get messed up with shared; pseduo leaks and lifetime hell follows.  Finally, moving unique is fixed cost, moving objects scale with object size/complexity.

Comment: Well then you've really sold me on shared_ptrs then. :-) I think maybe c pointers and references and good old using-destructors-to-free-objects (what the kids now call RAII) really were the better way... If ownership semantics get messed up, then what is the point. The whole purpose of smart pointers is to not have to worry about it. So if you have to worry about it, it obviously failed in its objective. And this was an improvement on auto_ptr...?

Comment: @stu shared ptr doesn't *solve* ownership in general, it solves *shared ownership*.  And shared ownership is only something you should rarely use.  Unique ownership is sane, and `unique_ptr` solves unique ownership.  I understand you dislike `move`, but move makes it *explicit* when ownership passes from one part of code to another, which is sane.  There is no "I don't have to think about ownership" -- even in full gc languages, you can leak resources if you ignore ownership.